# Map IdentityServer4 to "/identity", then map UI

Tags: asp.net-core-mvc, identityserver4

My application is basically this one: https://github.com/IdentityServer/IdentityServer4.Quickstart.UI

But I'm trying to map it to "/identity" using this piece of code:

```
app.Map("/identity", builder => { builder.UseIdentityServer(); });
```

It's working well, I can access `/identity/.well-known/openid-configuration` successfully.

However, if I try to connect, the application redirects me to `/identity/account/login`, which is on the IdentityServer side. IdentityServer cannot find my controller, so it returns me 404.

I tried to the LoginUrl property:

```
services.AddIdentityServer(options =>
{
    options.UserInteraction.LoginUrl = "/bleh/account/login";
})
```

But it also returns 404.

I also tried to make the Quickstart controller route the same as the redirect one:

```
[Route("identity/account/login")]
```

But it also returns 404.

Any idea?

Comment: in your map function did you try changing the default route for MVC to "identity/{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}" ?

Comment: @MuqeetKhan Did not work.

app.Map("/identity", builder =>
            {
                builder
                .UseIdentityServer()
                .UseMvc(routes =>
                {
                    routes.MapRoute(
                        "default",
                        "identity/{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
                });
            });

Comment: Did you ever find a solution to this? I'm having the same problem.

Answer (score 9):

If anyone is still looking for this.  This worked for me:

```
app.Map("/identity", builder => {
    builder.UseStaticFiles();
    builder.UseIdentityServer();
    builder.UseMvcWithDefaultRoute();
});
```

Comment: Make sure to also update (on your API) the `AddIdentityServerAuthentication` to include the `url/identity' like shown [here](https://github.com/benscabbia/identityserver4-dockersample-dotnetcore-nginx/blob/master/SampleApp.API/Startup.cs)